# RailsにMySQLを入れてrake db:create実行時のエラー解消方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql, rake

Rails 4.2.3にMySQL 5.6.27を入れてローカル環境で立ち上げようとしていますが、以下のエラーが出てrake dbができません。どうすればいいのでしょうか？

```
$ rake db:create

rake aborted!

LoadError:     dlopen(/Users/***/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0
/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.19/mysql2/mysql2.bundle, 
9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql
/lib/libmysqlclient.20.dylib

Referenced from: /Users/***/
.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions
/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.19/mysql2/mysql2.bundle

Reason: image not found - 
/Users/swati/.rbenv/versions/2.1.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions
/x86_64-darwin-14/2.1.0-static/mysql2-0.3.19/mysql2/mysql2.bundle

/Users/swati/Documents/Kluje_git/kluje/config
/application.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'

/Users/***/Documents/rails_project/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

環境　Mac　Yosemite 10.10.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mac(Yosemite)にMySQL 5.6とmysql2 gemをインストールする方法
http://blog.chopschips.net/blog/2015/02/15/macports-mysql2-gem/

rails + MySQL on OSX: Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557507/

どちらもシンボリックリンクでの解決が行われているようです。
そちらの環境では、libmysqlclient.20.dylibは何処に入っていますか？
問題なさそうであればシンボリックリンクで解決するか試してみてください。